# onActivityResult on Image capture does not show OK button after clicking picture

Tags: android, image-processing, android-camera-intent

So I am trying to take a pic with camera and pass it to another activity through intent to be shown in ImageView. Relevant code  -

```
    cameraBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE);
            }
            else
            {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        }


    });

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE)
    {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
@Override  
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CamCapture.class); //The problem seems to be  here somewhere
        intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I above code when I click cameraBtn icon in my Activity it has onclick listener which provides required permission to click image. After permission is granted camera opens. I click the image but after that the default ok button OR TICK button like this does not appear and image just gets saved -

[image]

If you may know that to go to next activity where i have ImageView to show captured Image it is necessary that i click on OK or TICK but the code just doesn't follow the required procedure.

Here is the CamCapture class code as requested by Dat Pham -

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.camImg);
image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: can you add the code of your `CamCapture` class?

Comment: I have added the CamCapture class code as requested

Comment: I meant the whole class, I am suspecting some slight issue with declaration of the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code crashes at `Intent intent = new Intent(this, CamCapture.class);` as you mentioned in your question, I suspect missing declaration on the `CamCapture` activity. Make sure that:

- `CamCapture` activity is public
- `CamCapture` activity is declared in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

I created a demo that uses your code, and it works correctly for me. You can find the demo on [github](https://github.com/phamtdat/CameraDemo)

How the code works on my device: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HZOg.jpg

Comment: Since you created a working demo of the code I am accepting this as an answer. I think code was just fine the way it is, the problem must have been with slow processing of emulator. My emulator was Nexus 5. What emulator was yours on which code is running successfully?

Comment: I run it on real device, seems like problem with your emulator probably.